# Justified text in iText 7 by stretching spaces between words

Tags: java, fonts, itext, itext7

I am trying to generate a justified text in iText 7 and am using TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED so far. Unfortunately, this seems to stretch ALL characters, instead of the spaces between the words, as usual in text-editing programs like word etc. Does sb know, how I can create such a paragraph in iText 7 without needing to hack it together myself?